# Why is my created date later than my updated date when I create a new row using SQLAlchemy with a Postgres database?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The title says it all but I am confused why when using this SQL Alchemy model I get a created date later than my updated date.

I ran this code at `08:57:53` and created says `2023-06-23 08:57:53.000` and updated says `2023-06-23 07:57:41.670`.

I am assuming it's to do with the server determining the update time but I would like them aligned to the same time zone.

What have I missed here as I'm pretty sure I didn't travel back in time by an hour and 12 seconds?

```
class Test(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tests'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(db.String(36), index=True, default=lambda:str(uuid.uuid4()))
    payload = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(JSONB))
    processed = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.utcnow(), nullable=False)
    updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.utcnow(), onupdate=dt.utcnow(), nullable=False)
```

With:

```
session = db.Session()
new_test = Test(
    payload = payload,
    processed = False,
    created = dt.fromtimestamp(processed_timestamp)
)
db.session.add(new_test)
db.session.commit()
db.session.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit as per the comments**

This is happening because of the way you set the value for `created` and the default value for `onupdate`.

`time.time()` returns the time since epoch but when you do `dt.fromtimestamp(processed_timestamp)` it gets converted into a naive datetime as per your local timezone which happens to be BST in your case.

`dt.utcnow()` returns the current UTC time, and as you know, BST is an hour ahead of UTC, which explains the difference you are seeing.

You have to ensure you use the same timezone before you populate, either use UTC (`utcfromtimestamp`) or BST (`fromtimestamp`) as per your application needs.

***With that being said, the earlier suggestion still stands, which is a problem you might face later.***

This is because you are calling `dt.utcnow` function here `default=dt.utcnow()`. Chances are you started your process around `2023-06-23 07:57:41.670` and that is the value returned that was set as default.

You should instead do `default=dt.utcnow` without `()` like so.

```py
created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.utcnow, nullable=False)
updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.utcnow, onupdate=dt.utcnow, nullable=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just made the change, deleted the table and retried and same thing.  I did it at 12:02 UK time, create is 12:02, updated is 11:02.  It's BST now but I thought timestamps had no awareness of it so I would expect both to be 11:02

Comment: @JohnnyJohnBoy if created is different, it is probably due to `processed_timestamp`, this is a value *you* are setting, the defaults are not used there, what is the value for `processed_timestamp` and how are you getting that?

Comment: It's processed_timestamp = int(time.time()) which is immediately preceding the session = db.Session().

Comment: I can use the updated as the source of truth but I'm just worried something is up.

Comment: @JohnnyJohnBoy `time.time()` returns the current BST time, and `utcnow` returns the utc time, which is obviously going to be different, this has got nothing to do with sqlalchemy, does that clear things for you?

Comment: @JohnnyJohnBoy I was slightly wrong in my previous comment, `time.time()` does not return the BST time, it returns the time since epoch but the actual conversion to local time is done when you do `dt.fromtimestamp` which results in BST, which happens to be your local time

Comment: That was it.. needed to change fromtimestamp to utcfromtimestamp.  If you update your answer I will mark it as correct.  Cheers for getting pointing me in the right direction..

Comment: @JohnnyJohnBoy I have made the changes in the recent edit